# Presto regular expression patter match multiple times

Tags: sql, regex, presto, regex-greedy

I'm trying to extract all the unicode characters of emojis using presto regexp_extract_all function, but its is storing everything as an individual element in the array. what is wrong with my regexp

sample text

```
{% case {{api_trigger_properties.${subj_line} | default: 1}} %}   {% when 1 %}     \u2614\ufe0f Today\u2019s forecast: Your favorite, no umbrella necessary.   {% when 2 %}     \U0001f4a6 Today\u2019s forecast: cold rain and warm, delicious     {% when 3 %}     \U0001f4a6 Looks like  weather in {{api_trigger_properties.${city} | default: 'your neighborhood'}}!   {% when 4 %}     You keep dry \u2614\ufe0f We\u2019ll keep delivering \U0001f697   {% when 5 %}     \U0001f327 Get out \U0001f64b\U0001f3fb\u200d\u2640\ufe0f\U0001f64b\U0001f3fe\u200d\u2640\ufe0f\U0001f64b\U0001f3ff\u200d\u2640\ufe0f    {% when 6 %}     ! \U0001f327   {% when 7 %}     \U0001f4a6 Perfect weather for letting us drop off your    {% when 8 %}     Hey, just dropping in about the rainy weather   {% when 9 %}     Rain alert! Order in and let us weather the storm   {% when 10 %}     {{${first_name} | default: 'Friend' | capitalize}}, we\u2019ll handle your rainy day    {% else %}     You keep dry \u2614\ufe0f We\u2019ll keep delivering \U0001f697 {% endcase %}
```

select statement

```
 select regexp_extract_all(subject, '\\(?i)u([0-9a-f]{4,8})*|\\(?i)u([0-9a-f]{4,8})')
```

output

```
{\u2614,\ufe0f,\u2019,\U0001f4a6,\u2019,\U0001f4a6,\u2614,\ufe0f,\u2019,\U0001f697,\U0001f327,\U0001f64b,\U0001f3fb,\u200d,\u2640,\ufe0f,\U0001f64b,\U0001f3fe,\u200d,\u2640,\ufe0f,\U0001f64b,\U0001f3ff,\u200d,\u2640,\ufe0f,\U0001f327,\U0001f4a6,\u2019,\u2614,\ufe0f,\u2019,\U0001f697}
```

expected output

```
'\u2614\ufe0f','\u2019','\U0001f4a6', '\u2019', '\U0001f4a6','\u2614\ufe0f', '\u2019', '\U0001f4a6', '\u2614\ufe0f', '\U0001f697', '\U0001f327', '\U0001f64b\U0001f3fb\u200d\u2640\ufe0f\U0001f64b\U0001f3fe\u200d\u2640\ufe0f\U0001f64b\U0001f3ff\u200d\u2640\ufe0f','\U0001f327','\U0001f4a6','\u2019','\u2614\ufe0f','\u2019'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
array_join(regexp_extract_all(subject, '\\u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4,8}'), ', ')
```

The `\\u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4,8}` regex matches `\u` and then four to eight hex letters/digits.

The `array_join(..., ', ')` joins the matches found with a comma + space.